# Valid JSON to display data in angularJs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, angularjs

I want to display data(json) in my site using AngularJs . here's what i did :
Create a database in phpmyAdmin .
Create a table with 2 row , subject and body . Should i create an id ?
After doing with PHP and angular , I got JSON like this :

```
[{
    "0":"Soheil","subject":"Soheil",
    "1":"Sadeghbayan","body":"Sadeghbayan"}
    ,{"0":"","subject":"","1":"","body":""}
    ,{"0":"","subject":"","1":"","body":""}
    ,{"0":"dasdasd","subject":"dasdasd","1":"qe","body":"qe"}
    ,{"0":"Hello","subject":"Hello","1":"This is chandler !","body":"This is chandler !"}
    ,{"0":"","subject":"","1":"","body":""},
    {"0":"Something new in website","subject":"Something new in website","1":"oh Awsome !","body":"oh Awsome !"
}]
```

I think this is invalid JSON because when I replace it with custom JSON that I wrote it work .

**Json valid**

```
{
    "fruits": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Apple"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Orange"
        }
    ]
}
```

**AngularJS**

```
var fruitsApp = angular.module('fruitsApp', []);

fruitsApp.factory('fruitsFactory', function($http) {
    return {
        getFruitsAsync: function(callback) {
            $http.get('fruits.json').success(callback);
        }
    };
});

fruitsApp.controller('fruitsController', function($scope, fruitsFactory) {
    fruitsFactory.getFruitsAsync(function(results) {
        console.log('fruitsController async returned value');
        $scope.fruits = results.fruits;
    });
});
```

**Html**

```
<ul>
            <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
                {{fruit.subject}} is {{fruit.body}}
            </li>
</ul>
```

**php**

```
    include('config.php');



$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$subject = mysql_real_escape_string($data->subject);
$body = mysql_real_escape_string($data->body);
mysql_select_db("angular") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO newstory (subject,body) VALUES ('$subject', '$body')");
Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database.";



$query = "SELECT * FROM newstory";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $subject = $row['subject'];
    $body = $row['body'];
    $arr[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Any idea ? Thx in advance

Comment: I tested your json using the following url and it is valid: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Just as Puttzy just stated in an answer. So seeing as the json is valid, perhaps your question is different. What is it you wish to do with this json and what did you already make in javascript?

Comment: Your json is valid: http://jsonlint.com/. Also are you using $resource? beause if your php is returning an array, the normal query need an object. so either you can change 'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true} in your js or you can do a exit(json_encode($value,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)); in the php

Comment: Thx guys,i updated my question with json valid

Comment: Both your jsons are valid. However if you wrote code to work with the 2nd one, of course your first one isn't going to get through it correctly.

Comment: why ?? maybe this is my mistake !!
i wrote angular code in my question

Comment: @StefanosChrs see my question please i updated

Comment: Console.log(results.fruits) will probably show you fruits is undefined. This is because your first Json doesnt have fruits in there.

Comment: @StefanosChrs no i'm not using $resource

Comment: @user3642164 you can try the fix I gave you above to put in your php so it can return an object

Comment: nothing happend !! sry

Comment: If you aren't going to change the first Json to contain a fruits collection then change the following $scope.fruits = results.fruits; to $scope.fruits = results; And you should be able to go from there.

Comment: i changed $scope.fruits = results.fruits; to $scope.fruits = results and it worked correctly but when i replace fruit.json to insert.php it just showed bullet from li in html ??!!!

THX man for your time

Comment: Your html should work (with your updated $scope.fruit assignment). How many blank "li"/bullets do you get on the page? Does that number equal the number of objects in your array?

Comment: yeah it's equal , i think insert.php has a problem

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is a valid. Refer to [this](http://json.org/) for information on JSON and [this](http://jsonlint.com/) to check/validate a JSON object.

The data coming back from your $http.get / database data does not have a `fruits` attribute and you expect that when you set your `$scope.fruits` (the below snippet is taken from your code):

```
 $scope.fruits = results.fruits;
```

The structure of the data that is being returned by the $http.get call is different than the format of your sample data.

Here's your $http.get / database data (I shortened it for brevity):

```
[
{
    "0": "Soheil",
    "1": "Sadeghbayan",
    "subject": "Soheil",
    "body": "Sadeghbayan"
},
{
    "0": "Hello",
    "1": "This is chandler !",
    "subject": "Hello",
    "body": "This is chandler !"
},
{
    "0": "",
    "1": "",
    "subject": "",
    "body": ""
}
]
```

And here's your sample / mock data:

```
{
"fruits": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Apple"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Orange"
    }
]
}
```

The former is an array of objects with keys: `0`, `1`, `subject` and `body`.
The latter is an object with keys: `fruits`.

*They are both valid JSON objects with different object structures.* But, you expect a `fruits` attribute where there isn't one. Also, your HTML/UI might be expecting the data format to look like what is in your mock data. So check that too.

Comment: thx maaan for doing this , i see what you mean , i changed $scope.fruits = results.fruits; to $scope.fruits = results and it worked correctly , but when i replace fruit.json to insert.php it just showed bullet from li in html

Comment: That's probably b/c your html logic is expecting "id" and "name" (the attributes in the fruits array from your mock data). But, instead your attributes are 0, 1, subject and body.